How to set-up SFTP for Pure-FTPd server in a container?
I have an issue, which I'm not getting right in my head and in the configs.
On my server a variety of services are running as (Docker) containers. Also a Pure-FTPd server (using https://hub.docker.com/r/gists/pure-ftpd's image).
Now, I will set-up SFTP (FTP over SSH), but I'm unsure how to do this.

As my server, running Docker, has SSH, is it possible to tunnel SFTP?
If that would be possible, I currently have no idea how to do it.
Or is the only way, to set-up another second ssh-server in the pure-FTPd container?

Thanks for your help,
Gerry

SFTP IS NOT FTP OVER SSH. SFTP is an entirely different protocol, albeit with similar capabilities, and is not implemented by PureFTPd; it is implemented (both server and client) by OpenSSH. In contrast FTPS is FTP over SSL/TLS and is implemented (if configured). You could tunnel (plain) FTP over SSH using OpenSSH (server either in container or in host given container has a fixed or determinable address) in front of PureFTPd, but only for passive mode with port restricted and IP faked.
